# How to integrate spring.io into wordpress?

Tags: spring, wordpress, spring-boot, spring-mvc, backend

I am working on a project and I was simply wondering how to integrate a backend surface made in spring.io into a wordpress website?

I read about converting wordpress into spring.io using JSON but I want to integrate a backend service for a front end wordpress.

If it works the results will be a backend service like database works with the wordpress website.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the community project [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a look.  The aim of this project is to quickly and easily create cloud-native, agile  "Content Services" with the Spring framework.  Essentially, exactly what you are asking for I think.

Best of luck!